# Adding constraints on table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am new to SQL Oracle.I have the following script:

```
create table students(
sid char(10),
honors char(10) not null,
primary key (sid),
Constraint studentConst foreign key (honors) references Courses(cid),
);

create table Courses(
cid char(10),
grader char(20) not null,
primary key (cid),
Constraint CoursesConst foreign key (grader) references students(sid),
);

SET CONSTRAINT studentConst,CoursesConst  DEFERRED;
```

I get the following error on running the above script:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier on line 5. Why do I get this error ?

Comment: are u supposed to have a ',' after Courses(cid) and students(sid)?

Comment: Oh..I removed the commas..but then how can I create these two table. I have added the constraints to be deferred. Yet I get "table does not exist" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can create a foreign key constraint on a table that doesn't yet exist.

Since you have a two-way constraint, you'll need to create the first table *without* the constraint, then add it with `alter table` *after* the second table has been created.

Deferred constraints are for checking *data.* Deferral simply means the check won't be carried out until the end of the transaction. It does not mean "defer the creation of the constraints so I can set up a circular reference" :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like line 5 is trying to reference `Courses(cid)`.  However, at this point, the `Courses` table does not exist, as it's created in the following SQL block.

Try creating dependent tables first.

Comment: Except they're _both_ dependent in this particular case :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add the constraint *after* the tables are built.  You can do this using an `alter table` statement:

```
create table students(
sid char(10),
honors char(10) not null,
primary key (sid)
);

create table Courses(
cid char(10),
grader char(20) not null,
primary key (cid),
Constraint CoursesConst foreign key (grader) references students(sid)
);

alter table students add constraint studentConst foreign key (honors) references Courses(cid)
```

The SQLFiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fd78).